# Homotopy Type of some space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let X = { a, b, c }, define a topology on X as open sets are {empty set, {b}, {a, b}, {b, c}, X}. Then I want to know the homotopy type of this space. Is it contractile?

Comment: Why are you tagging this with anything other than general topology? Differential geometry? Differential topology? At any rate, what are your thoughts?

Comment: These problems are basic for these persons

Comment: That's not how tagging works. Please stop abusing the tags or I'll have to flag this. Moreover, I am a differential geometer and I don't think about such non-Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: Hint: This is $[0,1]$ quotiented by the equivalence relation whose equivalence classes are $\{0\}$, $(0,1)$, and $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 2):

That space is contractible, indeed.

I suggest you read J. Barmak's book on finite topological spaces to learn how to prove this easily.